# Reduce gap between jquery mobile listview thumbnail and text

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have the following code I want to be able to reduce the gap between the thumbnail image and the description list inside each list view.

my css

```
.myParagraph.ui-li-desc {
      color:#333;
      overflow:show;
      white-space:normal;
      height:28px;
      margin-bottom:0px;
    }
```

my markup

```
 listitems_markup = '<li><img src="' + itemThumbnail + '"><div class="myParagraph"><ul data-inline="true" style="font-size:60%; font-weight:normal;"><li style="white-space:normal">You viewed ' + itemName + '</li><li style="white-space:normal">You spent '+itemTimeSpent+' on this activity</li><li style="white-space:normal">You '+itemRating+' this item</li><p class="ui-li-aside">'+itemViewedTime+'</p></ul></div></li>';
```

this is what it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to reduce the left padding for the list which is automatically set by most browsers.

```
ul{
padding-left:10px; //do not set this to 0 because of the list marks
border-left:0px;
margin-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Andras I have a problem with this, when I go to another page and come back the styling changes and it goes back to having a large gap

Comment: Make sure to use the same CSS code in my answer on every page you reach. (Rather use one css file for all styling than multiple pages of inline CSS)